# How to create MUI custom button?

Tags: typescript, react-typescript

I want to make my custom button(I'll call it `CustomButton`) based on MUI's `Button`. I want to preset button's background color.

For this, I made `CustomButton/index.ts` file like this:

```ts
import { Button } from '@mui/material';

interface CustomButtonProps {
  text: string;
  onClick: () => Promise<void>;
}

export default function CustomButton({ text, onClick }: CustomButtonProps) {
  return (
    <Button
      sx={{
        color: '#000000',
        backgroundColor: '#D9D9D9',
        '&:hover': {
          backgroundColor: '#959595',
        },
      }}
      onClick={onClick}
    >
      {text}
    </Button>
  );
}
```

I used two props(`text`, `onClick`) because each button has a different text and onClick function.

But I have a problem here. I should specify the type of `onClick` in `CustomButtonProps`. But what if the type of onClick functions are varied? Should I specify every types of them? If button A's onClick function's type is `() => void` and button B's onClick function's type is `() => Promise<void>`, should I write like this?
`(onClick: () => Promise<void>) | (() => void);`

Or is it better way to make `Button.css` file and import it? I'm a beginner in TypeScript and React, so I don't know what is the right way to make my own custom button.. :(